# Javascript function not getting called where required

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I made a javascript function and I called it from code behind. The Javascript is getting called only after the complete execution of the code behind and not in the part where I wrote the code using `ScriptManager`.. Can anyone explain this and provide me a solution to call the javascript where required.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn about server-side and client-side design.
Server-side code (.NET) occurs on server, while client-side code (Javascript) occurs on  client browser, only when the server-side processing has completed and the page has been sent and loaded into the client browser.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I need a way to call a Javascript in the middle of the server side execution. Is there any way for that??

Comment: Definitely not. Maybe if you show us some code we may help you to find a (proper) logic workaround